# Why username and hostname is quoted in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I found in many sources including the MySQL documentation, a statement like this appears

```
SHOW GRANTS for 'monty'@'localhost';
```

Example taken [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html). 
Note that both `monty` and `localhost` are quoted. I tried an unquoted version

```
SHOW GRANTS for monty@localhost;
```

in MySQL console, and I got exactly the same result.

Could anyone explain the reason why the two words are quoted in docs and tutorials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because MySQL user names can contain just about any character, including quotation marks and spaces. For example, this is completely legal syntax:

```
mysql> grant all on test.* to ' \\"\'@*.'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

If your user name contains non-alphanumeric characters like dots, spaces or quotation marks, then MySQL will throw an error unless it is enclosed in quotation marks and properly escaped with backslashes where necessary.

Comment: Thanks! So the quotation marks work like those in bash, for example? And it is safe to omit all quotation marks for hard-coded user names and host names if all characters are alphanumeric?